# JavaScript API от Яндекса + голосовой навигатор

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Такой вопрос: Мне нужно сделать в JS навигацию по яндекс картам с голосовой озвучкой(как в самом яндекс навигаторе). То есть при приближении к повороту, программа должна произнести "поверните на право" + передвижение производиться по пешеходным маршрутам. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Создать аналог Яндекс.Навигатора. Собрать команду из 100+ разработчиков, разрабатывать пару-тройку лет и у вас все получится!

Comment: "Как это реализовать?" - написать код.

Comment: Обратите внимание - бесплатную версию API Яндекс.Карт нельзя использовать для навигации и решения логистических задач (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/ ). В песочнице есть примеры: построение пешеходного маршрута (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_pedestrian ), получение сегментов маршрута (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/router ), определение местоположения пользователя (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolocation ).